# Fan fiction where Harry fails to send a letter to the Order

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, order-of-the-phoenix

I am looking for a story I read. It takes place during the summer. Harry is supposed to send letters to the Order, I think it is every three days, so they know that he is safe. Harry gets beaten by Vernon and he moves Harry back to the cupboard. Because of this, Harry can't send his letter, so Sirius, Lupin, Dumbledore and Severus go to Privet Drive to check on Harry. They find him in his cupboard and Snape uses a portkey to get to Hogwarts.

Does anyone know the name of the story and where I can find it?

Comment: Every three days is mentioned at https://m.fanfiction.net/s/1941294/1/To-be-a-Werewolf, but it doesn't help him.

Comment: Eeek, this is a very common trope that occurs in a lot of hp fanfics. Is there any other information you can give us? For example, do you remember when you read the fic? If it was a long/multi-chaptered fic? What site you read it on? I'm assuming it's in English, do you remember any other scenes or if there were any pairings?

Comment: It was in english, I read it on watpad. I think it was multiple chapters. After an order meeting, sirius and remus tells dumbledor how worried they are because they havent heard from harry. They go talk to the dursley and vernon tells them harry is in the cupboard under the stairs. When they find harry he is nearly dead from his injuries, snape uses his emergency portkey to get to the hospital wing and he and pomfrey work hard to save harry. I dont remeber more

Answer (score 2):

If it was read on Watpad, plausible match is [*He Will Be Loved*](https://www.wattpad.com/story/180150508-he-will-be-loved).

The adults who go to retrieve Harry match, with the addition of Moody, and the trigger was not receiving a letter from Harry every three days:

> "We've come to check on Harry, Mrs Dursley. We said we would send
> someone if we didn't hear from him every three days. I'm sure you
> remember." Dumbledore said mildly, stepping into the house.
>
> Severus, Alastor, Remus and Sirius followed

Snape uses a Portkey to take Harry directly to the hospital wing at Hogwarts, and he and Madam Pomfrey work to stabilise critical injuries:

> The portkey had taken them directly to the Hogwarts hospital wing, and as soon as they arrived Severus was calling out to Poppy, placing a still choking and convulsing Harry onto the nearest bed as the matron came running from her office.
> "Severus, don't just stand there! We need to stabilise him!" She snapped at the man, who had been hovering by the foot of the bed, his eyes glued to the boy who was now lying limply on the bed.
>
> Severus moved forward, joining Poppy as she worked to find and stem
> the source of the internal bleeding.10
>
> The next few minutes were spent in tense and apprehensive silence as
> the two of them worked together to bring Harry's vitals to a safe
> level, performing complex spells and gently coaxing potions down his
> unresponsive throat.